# How can I repeat each element in a sequence a different number of times in R

Tags: r

I've a sequence that goes from 1 to 3 and I need to repeat each value n + 1 times with n = 2. The way that I'm doing it now is:

> seq <- c(rep(1, each = n), rep(2, each = n+1), rep(3, each = n+ 2))
>
>  # [1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3

Is there a more concise way of writing that?

Comment: How about `rep(1:3, 2:4)`?

Comment: that's very useful. Thank you @AllanCameron